# Auth guard driver [api] is not defined. Lumen, Dingo, JWTAuth

Tags: jwt, lumen, dingo-api

I am trying to develop a rest api using lumen. For authentication I am using Dingo and JWTAuth api, but I am getting the following message:

> Auth guard driver [api] is not defined.

Below is a screenshot of the message from Postman, including the stacktrace.

[image: Postman screenshot of error]

Comment: Please do not post images of relevant text. Include the text in an appropriately formatted manner inside your question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In your `bootstrap/app.php` file, make sure the [following line](https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/v5.4.0/bootstrap/app.php#L82) is uncommented:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

This will cause the `api` auth driver to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `bootstrap/app.php` and uncomment (or add if you don't have them) the lines:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class);
```

And:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'auth' => App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
]);
```

And finally, run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```